# Error when running command in Cygwin terminal and Cylance protector

Tags: postgresql, terminal, cygwin

I am getting the below error when running command in `Cygwin` terminal and `Cylance protector` also installed in my PC.

```
 $ ./install_services.sh --uninstall-postgres
 1 [main] bash 529 C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxboro\cygwin\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error - MapViewOfFileEx 'cygpid.528'(0x33C), Win32 error 5.  Terminating.
Hangup
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Cylance is a known [BLODA](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.using.bloda).  You may need to disable it or, if it allows application or path-specific exceptions, configure it to ignore executables in your Cygwin installation.